# How to validate controls inside editform template of ASPxGridView?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an ASPxGridView with edit form template and some bound controls inside. After update I want to validate, check the values in controls on server side. As far as I could find this is not possible. DevExpress recommends subscribing to the RowUpdating event, but this is plain wrong. Useless as is very much of their so called support.
The problem is, that if controls contains some invalid text and it raises an exception somewhere long before RowUpdating and it gets eaten by devexpress. All it comes back to client is some message like "Input string was not in a correct format".
I want to validate input controls on the server side.
And yes, I do row validating also, but this is useful only for validating business logic.
So, how to validate controls that are bound inside EditForm template on server side?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please clarify? You want to validate the values *after* you update or actually before you write the values to the database or each control individually as it loses focus before you can initiate the update? If it is necessary to do server side validation then I would recommend doing it in the RowUpdating and RowInserting server side event handlers as was recommended by DevExpress. Why do you think this is wrong? You can validate each of the bound controls' values in the e.NewValues collection of grid's Updating and Inserting events. If any of the values do not pass validation you can cancel the update/insert action. Could you outline your desired workflow in a little more detail?

A previous poster said a hack was necessary, putting a container inside the edit form template, which is not true. You can use the edit form template itself via the .NamingContainer of any control in the edit form template. Put your validation routine in the server side _Validation event handler of the specific controls.
You can evaluate the template controls as a group:

```
EditFormValid = ASPxEdit
  .AreEditorsValid(myGrid.FindEditFormTemplateControl("myControl")
  .NamingContainer);
```

Or you can update a class variable during each control's validation routine

```
public class foo
{
  bool EditFormValid = true;
  .
  .
  .
  void myControl_Validation(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
  {
    EditFormValid = EditFormValid && myControl.IsValid;
  }

  void myGrid_RowUpdating(object sender, ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
  {
    If(EditFormValid)
    {
      .
      .
      .
    }
    else e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

I have found DevExpress extremely effective and flexible. However the flexibility can be a double edge sword as there are many ways to almost do everything you need most of the time but usually one way to do everything you need all of the time. A developer can easily build on top of what works in one instance but isn't necessarily right/best practice and get to a point where they have coded into a corner as they continue to build upon a project.

If you can provide more specifics, so can I.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible to do. Devexpress controls leave a lot to wish for. There is no way to check if validation was successful. Clearly a big issue.
What you can do is to run validation again with ASPxEdit.AreEditorsValid(). But for this you would have to do a little hack (as always with devexpress).
Put a container inside your edit form, a simple div with runat="server" and ID would do. This is your container.
Than get his div with FindEditFormTemplate() and use it in ASPxEdit.AreDitorsValid().
This workaround has drawbacks:

- clutters your aspx code with unnecessary elements
- page execution on    server side is slower
- page rendering on browser side is slower
- ValidateEditorsIncontainer() runs validation again so there is a big
  performance hit

All of the above are trademarks of DevExpress controls. But look at it from the bright side. Their grid sometimes takes up to five unnnecesary server and database roundtrips just to start editing.